# Why is my activity_main.xml not displaying all contacts in a list?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my **old** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_contact"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Old]

This is my **new** code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_contact" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: New]

As you can see, they're listed in the top one, but not in my new one. Does somebody know why?

Can't really explain without pictures...

Thanks in advance!

This is my item_contact.xml code since people asked for it. There's a lot of buttons and stuff like that but in reality what's more important is most likely the code at the top or maybe even the constraints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/wolfix_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/wolfix"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wolfix"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/block_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/block_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/block"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/block_button_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/call_button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/call_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/call"
        android:minWidth="48dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/user"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_number"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_image"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: will you add some java code below

Comment: In item_contact.xml please check android:layout_height="match_parent" and change it to wrap_content.

Comment: @Himani I don't think that will be a good approach.

Comment: @EAS why not. if the items are using match parent, there will be a massive space between items

Comment: please add some code? is your problem in the layout?

Comment: @a_local_nobody it can be, But all the items are already listed before

Comment: can you please add code of item_contact.xml. and also check the array size before assign adapter. So that you can find if there's issue of layout or data

Comment: Also add the code used to set up your RecyclerView

Comment: I'll add the code of item_contact.xml later today. I don't remember what the RecyclerView was used for, but I'll see if I can find it. It's also in Kotlin, so I can't really show it in Java form without altering everything.